# How to distinguish single/multiple button clicks in Python Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a score board in pygame.

```
score = 0

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

    if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        time.sleep(.2)
        screen.fill(w)
        score = score + 10
        score1 = str(score)
        text = "Score : "+score1
        myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
        label = myfont.render(text, 1, b)
        screen.blit(label, (10,10))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I don't want the player to be able to just hold down the mouse button down and the scoreboard keep counting.  Is there anyway that I could do this?  I am thinking of just for a first use game, counting how many clicks a person makes and then maybe calculate clicks per minute or something simple like that.

Comment: Why are you using `time.sleep(2)` in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your indentation is wrong. Your `if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` should be at the same level as `if event.type == QUIT:`.

Once you fix this, the code works as intended, since a `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event happens when you press the button. If you want to test if a button is down, you can get test it by calling `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`.

The problem might lay in the fact, that you are sleeping inside your event loop. This could lead to a freeze, since there might be more events to handle. If you want to reduce the frequency of the actions done by a click, you could create a timer, and check against that.

Comment: I think my indentation got messed up when I copied and pasted it over,  but thank you I will try to use this.